# how to wait for ThreadState.Abort?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

before calling:

```
th.Abort();
```

how can I wait for `ThreadState` to be `ThreadState.Abort` and then execute something? 
Is it possible?

Comment: @HansPassant - sure you can - you can start another thread to do the waiting and then call Abort().

Comment: @MartinJames:I thought it. But I put it as the last solution in my list..

Comment: I'II write it and paste it here as current solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call Thread.Join() [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx). Like this:

```
th.Abort();
th.Join();
```

The call to Join() will cause the calling thread to wait for that thread to terminate before continuing.

Also, you probably *shouldn't* call Thread.Abort() if your worker thread is interacting with pretty much anything else.

Comment: but, if the user want stop the process? how I'II do it without calling .Abort() method?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to use a BackgroundWorker which has cancellation baked in. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx .  Thread.Abort() is a brute force way to kill a thread and is only appropriate if you are sure there will be no side effects of an exception being raised at any moment on that thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a small loop to wait for the thread to abort.

```
th.Abort();
while (th.ThreadState.HasFlag(ThreadState.Aborted))
    Thread.Sleep(0);
// Thread is aborted.
```

Comment: There possibilities of it this never exit of loop? is better use `.HasFlag` instead?

Comment: Good point!  I didn't realise ThreadState was a Flags enum.  Edited above.

Comment: Um, should the condition should be `! xxx.HasFlag(...)` ?

Comment: @DahanGong, no, it will be `Aborted` until it actually terminates, and then it will be `Stopped`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstate?view=netframework-3.0

Comment: Hello, during my test on CSharp 7.x (.Net 4.5.2) on Win10 x64, an `Aborted` state won't switch to `Stopped` even when `Thread.IsAlive` is false; and sometimes a `.ThreadState` can even be `Running` after `.Abort()` (I've called `Thread.Yield()` but it's still possible to be `Running`).
So now I turns back to check `Thread.IsAlive` ...

Comment: Honestly, the other answer is better practice.